# Show some HTML only if the total price of all registration types selected by the user are > 0

Tags: php, laravel

In the view I have this foreach:

```
@foreach($selectedRtypes as $k => $selectedRtype)
    @foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $val)
    ....
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

And I want to show some html in the blade view if the total price of all registration types selected by the user are > 0.

Do you know how that can be achieved?

The "{{dd($selectedRtypes)}}" shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "general" => array:6 [▼
    "quantity" => "2"
    "price" => 5
    "subtotal" => 10
    "total" => 10
    "questions" => Collection {#243 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
    "id" => 1
  ]
  "plus" => array:6 [▼
    "quantity" => "1"
    "price" => 10
    "subtotal" => 10
    "total" => 20
    "questions" => Collection {#247 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    "id" => 2
  ]
```

I dont know if like below is correct because is only checking the price of one regitration type:

```
@foreach($selectedRtypes as $k => $selectedRtype)
    @foreach(range(1,$selectedRtype['quantity']) as $val)
    ....
           @if($selectedRtype['price']>0)
                <p>show this html</p>
            @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the price in another variable like 
`$price = 0;
$price = $price + $selectedRtype['price'];`

and then if the $price > 0, do something